# Make others li items animate from left to right when append one in the left with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I have a ul list that I get from a http call, that shows images and some text making some kind of cards.

Depending on the width of the screen I can show up to 4 of these cards, but I always receive more than that, so let´s say I have 5 of them

CARD CARD CARD CARD | CARD CARD

and I also have two buttons (one on the left and one on the right) to make the ul be a slider.

So, when I press the left button, the last li is taken from the end of the ul and goes first

```
function btnSlideLeft(ulId){
var cards = $('#' + ulId + ' li');
$('#' + ulId).prepend(cards[(cards.length -1)]);}
```

Now, what I need is for the whole list (all the li items) to move to the right smoothly.

I have tried adding some css:

```
.card-event{ //class of the li items
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
transition: all 1s ease-out;}

$(cards).each(function(){
    $(this).css({
    "-webkit-transform":"translate(" + (cardFinalWidth + 10) + "px)",
    "-ms-transform":"translate(" + (cardFinalWidth + 10) + "px)",
    "transform":"translate(" + (cardFinalWidth + 10) + "px)"
  });
});
```

I also tried with the jquery ui plugin

```
cards[(cards.length -1)].style.display = 'none';

$(cards[(cards.length -1)]).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
```

But, with the last option, the only thing I get is for the "appended" card to have its transition, but the rest of the cards just move from one position to another.

In one word, I am trying to make it work as a real slider and, unfortunatelly, using a plugin like slick is not an option.

Any ideas on what I can do to achieve that transition effect?

This is the HTML

```
<div id="carousel-pop-events" class="slick-container hidden-xs">
            <ul id="ul-pop-events-slider" class="wrapper wrapper-swiper swiper-wrapper relposition centered" style="width: 2000px;">
            </ul>
          <button class="ul-pop-events-slider slider-button slider-button-left ng-hide" type="button" onclick="btnSlideLeft('ul-pop-events-slider')"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
          <button class="ul-pop-events-slider slider-button slider-button-right ng-hide" type="button" onclick="btnSlideRight('ul-pop-events-slider')"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
```

and the function that creates the li items

```
function parseEvents(events, ulSlider){
try{
    $(events).each(function(){

        var data = this;
        var eventId = data["id"];
        if(data["images"].length > 0){
            var images = data["images"];
            $(images).each(function(){
                if(this["pivot"]["prinpal"] == "true"){

                    $('#' + ulSlider).append('<li class="popular-events noStyle card-event" onclick="getEvent(\''+ eventId +'\')"><img src="' + host + this["file_name"] + '"><div class="text-left"><b>Title</b><br>' + data["name"] + '</div></li>');
                }

            });
        }

    });
} catch (err){
    console.log(err);
}

toExecuteAfterJson();}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the appropriate HTML as well.

Comment: Right @Gianpolo. As a matter of fact, now, in developing mode, I am receiving li1 to 6 and 5 and 6 are out of view

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why slider plugins are not an option? They are basically free code that provides the functionality you ask for, in a controllable manner. Most times, custom code is worse than such plugins, as it tends to not be as well tested as those plugins have been.

Comment: Client requirement. And besides, most of them (I have tried slick and swiper) don´t allow you to have a background and in some sliders I need to put some kind of "kind of rounded" background gradient.